# Is there Page bulk manager?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I tried to look for bulk page manager for Drupal 7, but I wasn't successful. More specifically, I'd like to change access settings for multiple pages in one step. Something similar to what [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) provides for entities.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

## Content Access VBO

Maybe you want to look at [Content Access VBO](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/scott_shipman/2083709) ... It's (still) a sandbox project, so not sure if you really want to consider it. Here are some details about it (quote from that link):

> ... creates an action for [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to update per node content access (view/edit/delete etc). It adds a menu item to the Content menu tree and adds a new view which lists content with the VBO action as a button.

But at least it may help to get more inspiration to build your custom module to get this done.

## Combine Rules with Views Bulk Operations or Content Access

Another approach is to use the Rules module, combined with modules [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and/or [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access). Here are a few questions that may help to get more inspiration about its possibilities (the sky is the limit ...):

- [Is there a module that lets one person do a bulk publish/update?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165501/is-there-a-module-that-lets-one-person-do-a-bulk-publish-update/165522?s=2|0.2044#165522)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159988/how-to-implement-a-complex-workflow-in-a-website-with-subsites-and-using-opensch/161616?s=8|0.2610#161616
- [How can an author mark the update date of a node to be visible or hidden for visitors?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165392/how-can-an-author-mark-the-update-date-of-a-node-to-be-visible-or-hidden-for-vis/165415?s=9|0.2434#165415)
- [Is there a module that lets one person do a bulk publish/update?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165501/is-there-a-module-that-lets-one-person-do-a-bulk-publish-update/165522?s=13|0.1373#165522)
- [How do I publish nodes 3 times a day?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159646/publish-nodes-3-times-a-day/159670?s=1|0.2062#159670).

Comment: Thanks, but all these solutions seems to be related to entities, not Ctools Pages. I'll look into the CA VBO module, but it seems to be using very different concepts.